# Communicate forms in two pages (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, forms, parameters

I have a form that requires another model to be saved before the first one:

I create a Proposal, and the proposal may have 1:n new Projects. When want to add a new Project, I have to save it first, choosing a base project (Already saved) and filling the wanted changes (In another tab). 
[image: Form 1]
[image: Form 2]

When it's finished, I want to pass the saved project ID to the main form (Proposal), to a hidden field, to be saved.

Is there a way to use a value from this other form in another tab, on the first one? (Using Javascript)

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Can you give some more details on how you have build your application?

*Do you render different tabs with javascript and do you save the project with an asynchronous call?*

If this is the case, you can have the rails controller to return the id of the new project and store it in a hidden field with jQuery. `$(hidden-field-selector).val(id)`.

*Are you redirecting between tabs (the rails way)?*

Then you can add this id in a hidden field in your view. Perhaps this is not what you are looking for since you want to use javascript.

Comment: I'm using the rails way, with the 'target: _blank'. But I'm not sure if this is the best way... How do I create a tab with javascript?

Comment: Oh, you meant a browser tab. I thought a tab as displayed on your website. In this case I think you could set cookies, that might be easier than doing cross tab javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this API: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage. 
You need to register an event listener that listens to this value, and to fire the event once it's ready.
You should have a handle for the opened tab otherwise you can't do it.